# Gets Data in Json Format From AngularJs Controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having a hard time with `AngularJs`. It works accordingly in some cases for me and when I try to change the template of the project, it doesn't work anymore. Here is the scenario - I have a controller in `ASP.NET MVC` that returns the list of products in `Json` format and finally I call this controller using `AngularJs` controller as follows:

**C#**:

```
public JsonResult GetProducts()
{
    var result = (from c in db.Products
                  select new { c.ProductName, c.Price }).ToList();

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**AngularJs**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ProductController', function ($scope, ProductService) { 
    $scope.Products = null;

    ProductService.GetProducts().then(function (d) {
        $scope.Products = d.data;

    }, function () {
        alert('Failed');
    });
});

app.factory('ProductService', function ($http) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.GetProducts = function () {
        return $http.get('/Product/GetProducts');
    }
    return factory;
});
```

In the UI, I've used the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Get Products</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../AngularFile/AddToCart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Get Products</h2>
        <div ng-app="app" class="container">
            <br /><br />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
            <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
            <div ng-controller="ProductController">
                <table class="table table-responsive" ng-repeat="m in Products">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ m.ProductName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.Price }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output I am getting is this:

[image: Sample Products]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. In my earlier project, using the same code, it shows products properly but right now, I am getting data in `Json` format. Is this common and anyone faced like this before?

**Note**: If I change the method type from `JsonResult` to `ActionResult`, it shows nothing.

Comment: try to transfer your ng-repeat in <tr>

Comment: Tried @Barclick Flores Velasquez but didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: 1. ProductService.GetProducts().then(function (d) { console.log(d), check your response, 2. ng-repeat="m in Products" -> to tr, 3. Controller name startWith lowercase -> productController

Comment: Done everthing @Dmitry Matrosov. Nothing yet.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. It should generate a table for each item in the Products array.

Comment: Yes @Shyju. But unfortunately, this is driving me crazy and still unable to make it work.